# first kernel space driver in -- linux

Tags: coding-style, raspberry-pi, embedded-linux, hardware-port

I was able to control GPIO using mmap system call to control LED operation directly from the user space. Now I want to implement driver in kernel space.

I am trying to write my first kernel space device driver for 16*2 line of LCD in Linux for ARM controller RPi.
Now i need to access the GPIO for this purpose.

In AVR i use to access the Port like this.

```
#define PORTA  *(volatile unsigned char*)0x30
```

I was reading LLD it tells to use inb() & outb() function to access the i/o port.
http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-2

1> Can we not use #define address of port to access the GPIO ?

2> What is the advantages to use use inb() & outb() functions for controlling the GPIO ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) the use of defines simplifies your task often. You could, of course, not use define for your port and use this construction literally everywhere you need to access the port. But then you will have to replace the 0x30 everywhere with another address if you change the design of your device, for example, if you decide to connect your LED to port B. Also, it will make your code less readable. Alternatively you could declare a function that will access your port. If such a simple function is declared `inline` (if your compiler supports inlines) then there is no difference in performance.

2) the advantage of using `inb()` and `outb()` is portability of your program. If this is not an issue, then it is fine to access your port directly.

Comment: i think inb() uses i/o address space to read port instead of using memory mapped space.

Comment: what do you mean by portability of program ?

Comment: Please read this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_portability for the definition.

Comment: Let's say you switch to another CPU model from the same vendor, or compatible one, that has no separate IO address space but provides the ports at the same addresses as the original product. Then you just use the compiler options to tell it the architecture you are building your program for and it switches between two different access methods seamlessly.

Comment: Of course, when we are speaking about embedded development such a flexibility could rarely have a place, but still using of the compiler builtins may save your development costs. Anyway, you should check with the docs for your case. The question was more or less generic and so I provided a generic answer. You always should take to account all specifics when you make a choice.

Comment: thanks for your help.....> got the point that inb() function will hide the details for accesing i/o port inside it ---> and we can use it on any other controller which is using ARM from portability point of view ---> because implementation of accessing the port i hidden behind the inb() & outb() functions.

Comment: @Katoch - *"i think inb() uses i/o address space..."* -- No, RP uses an ARM SoC, which has memory-mapped I/O. There is no I/O address space nor I/O instructions like x86.

Answer (score 1):

> In AVR i use to access the Port like this.

```
#define PORTA  *(volatile unsigned char*)0x30
```

That's an improper definition that overloads the symbol `PORTA`.
Besides defining the port address as 0x30, you are also dereferencing that location.
So it is actually a *read* operation, but there's no indication of that in the name, i.e. you have really defined a macro for `READ_PORTA`.

> 1> Can we not use #define address of port to access the GPIO ?

Of course you can (and should).

```
 #define PORTA (unsigned char *)0x30
```

You'll find similar statements in header files for device registers in the Linux source tree.  When developing a new device driver, I look for a header file of `#defines` for all of the device's registers and command codes, and start writing one if no file is already available.

> 2> What is the advantages to use use inb() & outb() functions for controlling the GPIO ?

The code is then an unambiguous statement that I/O is being performed, regardless of whether the architecture uses I/O ports or memory-mapped I/O.
Anyone reading the following should be able to deduce what is going on:

```
x = inb(PORTA);
```

versus the confusion when using your macro:

```
x = PORTA;
```

The above statement using an overloaded macro would not pass a code review conducted by competent coders.

You should also get familiar with and use the [Linux kernel coding style](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/CodingStyle).